# php variable actual value not being inserted into table

Tags: php, html, mysql

**html form**

```
<html><body>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
Headline:<input type="text" name="head"><br>
Content:<Textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="cont"></textarea>
</form>
</html>
```

**my table structure**
two fields are headline,content.

**Filling the form:**
Headline- "this is crazy"
Content- "here i want to put image like this..
          `<img src="$image" />` "

**Process.php**

in this i get Headline and content from form in two php variable
`$headline=$_POST['head'];
$content=$_POST['cont'];`

here i have one variable `$image` which contains address of image like: `$image contains "img\thumb\2.jpg"`

i've to insert `$headline` and `$content` into table.

**problem**
whenever i insert headline and content into table... headline goes fine into table..but in content it shows: `"here i want to put image like this..
&lt;img src=&quot;$image&quot; /&gt; "`

why `$image` actual value is not getting parsed?
any solution?

Comment: Can you show the full code of the page, or at least the section, that has the content and `<img />` tag? The HTML form you have doesn't have the image tag in it and your sample output doesn't help much either.

Comment: ok let me explain.... firstly i upload image thru different php script, and store its address in "$image". now say 
$image look like "$image=img\thumb\2.jpg".Thru my html form im uploading "headline"and "content" in database using INSERT. I want to use $image variable in "content"field of html form. but it takes "content" containg $image variable as string. when i open table to see content it contains "$image" instead of "img\thumb\2.jpg" .

Comment: @newfurniturey:  i will upload code soon..

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually "in PHP" when you're attempting to output it.

In other words, you have to open a PHP section to echo the variable:

```
<?php echo $image; ?>
```

or, with your image tag:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
```

Comment: @user2320375 Are you sure? If you say that `$image` contains an actual text value and you do `<?php echo $image; ?>`, it will work... period. Can you verify that `$image` has a value and that you've properly spelled the variable in all instances of using it?

Comment: @newfurniturey: ya im sure.... i tried this yesterday... but no use.... ya it has value

Answer (score 0):

It's  because when you write $image into HTML textarea, it's treated as a string not as variable.

So, you should write the full image URL to your database, something like img\thumb\2.jpg and then read it to the browser.

Comment: ya exactly ! its treated as string... i have to use this page multiple times. so again n again i cant put exact address... it will be cumbersome... so want to use script only..

Answer (score 0):

Use [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) Convert all HTML entities to their applicable characters

```
html_entity_decode($content);
```

Example

```
$b = html_entity_decode("I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now");

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
```

Comment: i need to insert content into table field "content" so i used htmlspecialcharacter() , without this it wont get inserted into table.. while inserting into table i want it to be encoded only...

Answer (score 0):

See when you are trying to input special characters like <, >, & etc. they are converted into their HTML formats like < is converted into &lt;, similarly > is converted into &gt;. Thats why when you are trying to insert < or > symbol in database it is inserting it like &lt; and &gt;. You shouldn't use them like this. But if you really need them you can replace &lt; with < and &gt; with > just before Insert query.

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO TEST (HEAD, CONTENT) VALUES (" . $head . ", " . $content . ")";
$qry = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $qry);
$qry = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $qry);
```

and then you can use $qry for insertion.